# How to handle "white space" that are not null and cannot be trimmed?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Look at the screenshot of SSSMS. There are some "white spaces". I am trying to update them to 0, but failed. I tried:

1. `LTRIM(RTRIM(COL_NAME))`
2. `Update Where COL_NAME IS NULL`
3. Copy & paste the 'white space' to `where`clause.

The datatype is nvarchar.

`isnumeric(colname)` shows they are not numeric.

The output of `cast as varbianry`

```
0x
0x
0x
0x
0x
0x
0x
0x
0x
0x
```

[image]

Comment: what's the column you are referring to?

Comment: @vkp The last column in blue.

Comment: What do you get if you cast the column to `varbinary`?

Comment: @MartinSmith Genius. See the update.

Comment: So that means they are all zero length. They are just empty strings.

Comment: ergo the problem was the update is `where col_name is null` instead of `where col_name = ''`

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to replace other whitespace characters like carriage return, new line, and tab (13,10,09).

```
... replace(replace(replace(col,char(13),''),char(10),''),char(9),'')

update ... 
where nullif(ltrim(rtrim(replace(replace(replace(col,char(13),''),char(10),''),char(9),''))),'') is null
```